# Ionic osmtogeojson module

Tags: ionic3, openstreetmap, geojson

I am using [this module osmtogeojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/osmtogeojson) inside my **home.ts** file

import osmtogeojson from 'osmtogeojson';

I linked my project **ionic link --pro-id project_id**.
Pushed the code **git push ionic master**.

However, **Build failed**:

> ionic-app-scripts build

```
[20:40:08]  ionic-app-scripts 3.1.9 
[20:40:08]  build dev started ... 
[20:40:08]  clean started ... 
[20:40:08]  clean finished in 2 ms 
[20:40:08]  copy started ... 
[20:40:08]  deeplinks started ... 
[20:40:08]  deeplinks finished in 65 ms 
[20:40:08]  transpile started ... 
[20:40:20]  typescript: node_modules/osmtogeojson/index.d.ts, line: 1 
            Cannot find module 'geojson'. 

       L1:  import { FeatureCollection, Feature, GeometryObject } from 'geojson';

[20:40:20]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[20:40:20]  Error: Failed to transpile program 
Error: Failed to transpile program
    at new BuildError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:159:20
    at new Promise ()
    at transpileWorker (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:64:12)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:109:82
    at 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! urbanRefuge@0.0.1 build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the urbanRefuge@0.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gitlab-runner/.npm/_logs/2018-05-19T20_40_20_995Z-debug.log
npm run build failed
Running after script...
$ run "clean-up"
Running Stage clean-up for Job: 5565766
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: The solution: I just installed geojson **npm i geojson**

Comment: Post your solution as an _answer_ and _accept_ it, so that people know your issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `npm i geojson` and your issue will be resolved